# Cannot Accept Answer on Old Post

Tags: support, questions, answers, accepted-answer

I just stumbled across an [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143640/aliasing-resources-wpf) of mine, realising it didn't yet have any accepted answer. However, when I viewed the page, I noticed that the tick marks for accepting answers had all disappeared. Is this by design - if not, what's up here?

Comment: Was it a bounty question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you previously set up a bounty on that question? Questions that have a [bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1413/1414#1414) expire without an accepted answer can never have an accepted answer. In your reputation history you have a -50 for that question, which almost always suggests a bounty was offered.

Comment: Yeah, this seems to be what happened. Forgot about that rule with bounties. It's a shame, because only after the bounty ended did I realise that one of the solutions provided was essentially correct.

Comment: I thought that bounty questions were supposed to automatically "accept" highest voted answer if OP didn't accept one?

Comment: @DVK: only if an answer gets at least two upvotes after the bounty is offered

Answer (score 9):

The existing accepted answer to this question — *this* MSO question, not the SO question that it's asking about — is wrong, although it was correct at the time that it was written.

On June 18, 2010, [the bounty system changed](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improvements-to-bounty-system/). Bounties and accepted answers are now completely independent creatures. A happy side effect of the change is that **it is now possible to accept old answers such as these**.

This answer is just for future reference; you can clearly see that the OP already went back and [awarded that richly deserved green checkmark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143640/aliasing-resources-wpf/1144057#1144057).